# Change package manager in Expo

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

Everytime that I run `expo init myprojct`, Expo asked me that it find Yarn and did you want to use Yarn or not. one time I choose No, and expo from that day used NPM, now I want to use Yarn as my default package manager for Expo. so how to set yarn as a default package manager for Expo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
 expo init myproject --yarn
```

Comment: is there a config setting for this if you didn't init with this?